# highchartsのグラフ描画について

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

highchartsでグラフを描いています。

棒グラフのデータの数は2つだったり、1つだったりします。例えば、`data: [29.9, 71.5]`が`data: [71.5]`の場合があります。

棒グラフとX軸のラベル(`Jan`や`Feb`)の位置があってる状態で右揃えで表示したいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか？

あともうひとつラインチャートを追加した状態で右揃えにしたいのですが可能ですか？

以下のコードのように`plotOptions`を設定したのですが、期待通りに表示されませんでした。

**コード**

https://jsfiddle.net/koonii26/2tqha4rf/1/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 10,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 1,
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: `groupPadding`(デフォルト値0.2)の設定値により棒グラフの片方が画面外まで行ってしまっていますが…それとは別に、「データの数が2つだったり、1つだったりします。」というのは、`data: [0, 71.5]`だったりするという事でしょうか？それとも棒グラフがあったりラインチャートがあったり、という意味でしょうか？また右揃えにしたい「ラベル」とはグラフ内のどの項目を指していますか？1つの質問の中に複数の疑問が混ざっているよう見えますので少し質問文を [編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/73950/edit) して整理してみてください。またラインチャートを表示するために試したことなどもあれば追記してください。 [公式サイトのサンプル](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes) などもあります。

Comment: data: [29.9, 71.5]がdata: [71.5]の場合があります。ラベルとはjanやFebそれぞれを指しています。

Comment: borderWidth: 10,pointPadding: 0,groupPadding: 1　それぞれを値を変更するとかはやったのですがだめでした

Comment: 右揃えというのはこんな感じでしょうか？ https://jsfiddle.net/6ophskyx/

Comment: ありがとうございました。